# Have several classes implementing ContentProvider Android App?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm currently developing an Android app. I'm using a ContentProvider to manage my database. Thing is, I'm doing my app module by module, one step at a time. My Content Provider works just fine, I have like 10 tables for one module and it works great.

I'm going to start a new module that has at least 10 more tables, and like that module I have like 5 more so my database is going to be a little big.

**Is there a way I can have several classes implementing ContentProvider?** One class for each of my modules, for example. I could do all just in one class but that seems just... ugly, and that file is going to be enormous.

I thought of creating an interface that extends ContentProvider and depending on what I want to get from the database, call the proper class, but ContentProvider is already an interface so that wouldn't work.

Hope anyone can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it? What difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: haha no I haven't tried, I'm asking before doing it, just in case :D

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely have multiple classes which implement `ContentProvider`. Nothing limits the number of content providers you deploy in a given app. Remember that you must register a `ContentProvider` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. One of the pieces of information you must provide with a `<provider>` tag is the URI which is directed towards that provider. This suggests that you simply give a different URI for each provider. You will just need to develop a scheme for your URI naming.

Comment: so I could have one provider for my users module, a different provider for another module and so on?

Comment: ok, I'm going to try it! thanks!